# Rewrite IIS URL to Point at Subfolder for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I've got three installations of Wordpress on the same server, and they're with the following layout:

```
Site1
Site1\Site2
Site1\Site3
```

I have four URLS www.site1.com, www.site2.co.uk, www.site2.com and www.site3.co.uk. I'd like to set up URL rewriting in a web.config file so that the URLs point to their corresponding folders. Also I need the Wordpress installations to use Permalinks.

This is my set up (completely not working) at the moment:

```
<rule name="site1" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*"/>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="*www.site2.co*" ignoreCase="true" negate="true"/>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="*www.site3.co*" ignoreCase="true" negate="true"/>
                <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="*site2*" negate="true"/>
                <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="*site3*" negate="true"/>
            </conditions>
        </rule>v
        <rule name="site2" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*"/>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="site2/index.php"/>
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="*www.site2.co*" ignoreCase="true" negate="false"/>
                <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="*site2*" ignoreCase="true" negate="false"/>
                <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="*wp-admin*" negate="true"/>
                <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="*wp-content*" negate="true"/>
                <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="*wp-login*" negate="true"/>
            </conditions>
        </rule>
        <rule name="site2-content" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*"/>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="site2/{R:0}"/>
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="*www.site2.co*"/>
                <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="*wp-content*"/>
            </conditions>
        </rule>
        <rule name="site2-admin" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*"/>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="site2/{R:0}"/>
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="*www.site2.co*"/>
                <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="*wp-admin*"/>
            </conditions>
        </rule>
        <rule name="site2-login" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*"/>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="site2/{R:0}"/>
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="*www.site2.co*"/>
                <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="*wp-login*"/>
            </conditions>
        </rule>
    <rule name="site3" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*"/>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="site3/index.php"/>
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="*www.site3.co*" ignoreCase="true" negate="false"/>
                <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="*site3*" ignoreCase="true" negate="false"/>
                <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="*wp-admin*" negate="true"/>
                <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="*wp-content*" negate="true"/>
                <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="*wp-login*" negate="true"/>
            </conditions>
        </rule>
        <rule name="site3-content" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*"/>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="site3/{R:0}"/>
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="*www.site3.co*"/>
                <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="*wp-content*"/>
            </conditions>
        </rule>
        <rule name="site3-admin" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="*"/>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="site3/{R:0}"/>
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="*www.site3.co*"/>
            <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="*wp-admin*"/>
        </conditions>
        </rule>
        <rule name="site3-login" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*"/>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="site3/{R:0}"/>
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="*www.site3.co*"/>
                <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="*wp-login*"/>
            </conditions>
        </rule>
        <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="*"/>
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
        </rule>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have your three wp installations in three different IIS sites?

Comment: Yes, yes it would :) But this is shared box. So I can't do that.

Comment: It's regrettable that there are so few insights into these issues with wordpress and URL-rewriting on IIS... I'm also facing a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18881021/1426433