# IIS Url Rewrite for Wordpress subfolder site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, iis, url-rewrite-module

I run two separate Wordpress instances one in the root folder and one in a subfolder. These Wordpress instances runs on IIS.

I got the permalinks to work on the root wordpress instance. But it doesn't work on the wordpress in the subfolder.

I am trying with a separate web.config in the subfolder with this ruleset. But it will not work correctly. What can be wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="90-Numre" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="^90-numre/index.php/{R:0}" /></rule>
            <rule name="wordpress1" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="^90-numre\index.php" />
        </rule>     
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />

        <add value="index.php" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors defaultRedirect="" mode="RemoteOnly" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have copied it from the web.config from the root folder and added what I thought where the correct subfolder info.

Comment: I can see that the .htaccess for the rootfolder WP instance is 
`code`
this:#Options +FollowSymLinks
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.website.com/90-numre/$1 [R=301,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 5000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 5000
 `code`

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to: [MVC3 + WordPress IIS Url Rewriting Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068932/mvc3-wordpress-iis-url-rewriting-rules?lq=1)

I found the trick:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
            <match url="*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="/mymvcapp/*" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>     
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```